# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore required query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Core v2.1 project with `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package.
My code is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set new android token for the current driver
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    ///
    ///     PUT /SetToken?token=new_token
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="token">can't be null or empty</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <response code="204">If executed successfully</response>
    /// <response code="400">if token is null or empty</response>  
    /// <response code="404">if user is not a driver; if driver is not found (removed etc); if user does not have a profile</response>  
    [ProducesResponseType(204)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("SetToken")]
    [UserIsNotDriverException]
    [NullReferenceException]
    [DriverWithoutProfileException]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SetToken([FromQuery]string token)
    {
```

I want to mark query parameter as required. How can I do it? Pay attention, I pass parameter in query string, not inside body etc

Comment: The query string is inherently optional. That's just HTTP spec. If you need to require something, it should be part of the route (i.e. the actual URL path). That said, methods like POST and PUT have a request body, and the proper place for data is in the body. You should pretty much never be using query strings with something like a PUT.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add the [BindRequired](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/#flag-required-parameters-and-schema-properties) attribute to your parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SetToken([FromQuery, BindRequired]string token)
```

Comment: This requires at least .Net Core 2.1 in order for "ModelState.IsValid" to function correctly, see: https://andrewlock.net/coming-in-asp-net-core-2-1-top-level-mvc-parameter-validation/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SetToken([FromQuery, SwaggerParameter("Token Description", Required = True)]string token)
```

Using this library `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` will help.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to this case, if you bind a complex model (i.e. a POCO) to the query parameters and you need Swagger to require some properties inside the model to be required, it works by adding the `Required` attribute to each property.

As a side note, there is no need to use `BindRequired` or similar in the action function declaration.